# Get Firebase unique ID from filtered object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, firebase, javascript-objects

I’m building an Angular app that searches geographic locations through the 500px API and returns photos based on the search. If someone searches the same location multiple times, I’ll need to increment the search for `page=x` on the API request, so that fresh results are returned.

My current way of handling this is to query all my `locations` in Firebase, and filter through them using Undescore.js `_findWhere` feature. If a location name matches the searched term, I increment it, otherwise I create a new one.

Currently I have it working so that my object is being returned when it matches, but in order to increment it, I need the unique ID of that object that Firebase assigned to it.

Here's my code (converted from CoffeeScript; apologies):

```
getSearchCount = function(result) {
  var data;
  // fetch the data from firebase as an object
  data = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
  return data.$loaded().then(function() {
    var passed_data, plucked_result;
    // search the object to see if a location matches the currently searched term
    plucked_result = _.findWhere(data.locations, {
      name: result.formattedAddress
    });
    // this is where I want to return the unique ID of the plucked result
    return passed_data = [result, plucked_result];
  });
};

saveLocation = function(passed_data) {
  var plucked_result, result, search_count;
  result = passed_data[0];
  plucked_result = passed_data[1];
  // if the search term doesn't exist, create a new one
  if (plucked_result === null) {
    search_count = 1;
    return locationsRef.push({
      name: result.formattedAddress,
      lat: result.lat,
      lng: result.lng,
      search_count: search_count
    });
  } else {
    // increment the search count on the query
    // search_count = plucked_result.search_count + 1
    // plucked_result.search_count = search_count
  }
};
```

Here's the object I’m getting returned for console.log(data):

```
d {$$conf: Object, $id: null, $priority: null, foo: "bar", locations: Object…}
  $$conf: Object
  $id: null
  $priority: null
  locations: Object
    -JUBNhmr_0kwSmHLw4FF: Object
      lat: 51.5073509
      lng: -0.12775829999998223
      name: "London, UK"
      search_count: 1
    __proto__: Object
    -JUBQREGJpQnXxiMIaKm: Object
      lat: 48.856614
      lng: 2.3522219000000177
      name: "Paris, France"
      search_count: 1
  __proto__: Object
  __proto__: Object
  photos: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

Here's the object I’m getting return for console.log(plucked_result):

```
Object {lat: 51.5073509, lng: -0.12775829999998223, name: "London, UK", search_count: 1}
```

So, to summarise, I want the Firebase unique ID (-JUBNhmr_0kwSmHLw4FF).

Or perhaps I’m doing this in a completely convoluted way that could be simplified? All I essentially need to do it create a way of paginating my API request so that I’m not pulling in all the same page of results twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**:

You can replace the underscore.js `findWhere()` call with a loop like this:

```
var key;
var location;
for(key in data.locations) {
  location = data.locations[key];
  if(location.name == result.formattedAddress) {
    break;
  }
}
```

This will yield your object of interest stored in `location` and its name in `key`.

**Why this is the case**

The unique id that you're looking for (which the Firebase docs call the object name) is the parent of your location object in your firebase. One object in `data.locations` might look something like this:

```
{ '-JUBNhmr_0kwSmHLw4FF' : 
    { lat: 51.5073509, lng: -0.12775829999998223, 
      name: "London, UK", search_count: 1 }
}
```

And the `findWhere()` function can locate it, but it only returns the matched object and does not provide a way to step up the tree one to get the parent node.